# After deploying my code in vercel, its showing my code instead of data

Tags: deployment, vercel, feathersjs

i have a problem with deploying in vercel after deploying my code (writen in fethersjs and typescript) showing code instead of data
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HXrrq.png)
this is how.

My vercel.json conf

```
{
    "version": 2,
    "devCommand": "npm run dev"
}
```

I tried every thing but no results.